# React cannot use import as component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React and i'm stuck with a problem that I don't understand...

Let's say I have this component created in it's own file

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const menuBar = () => (
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/manageUsers">About</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
    </div>
);

export default menuBar;
```

Which I use in App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import login from './login';
import manageUsers from './manageUsers';
import menuBar from './menuBar';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Router>
        <switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={login} />
          <Route path="/manageUsers" component={manageUsers} />
          <hr />
          <menubar />
        </switch>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I tried to run that, all my others components worked (login and manageUsers) but i'm not able to show the component menuBar...

I guess it's probably a syntax error but I cannot find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component should be Capitalized name.

```
// as you have exported as default, you can use any name (not just MenuBar)
// but just care to name it with capitalized first letter.
import Menubar from './menuBar';

<Menubar />
```

Alternatively, you could still use lowercase component name as you just have the functional component, call like this:

```
import menubar from './menuBar'
{menubar()}
```

Comment: Now I feel stipid... Thanks for the quick answer!!

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing it like this:

```
import menuBar from './menuBar';
```

See: menu**B**ar.

But you are using as menu**b**ar.

Also, start your component names with a capital letter like **Menubar**. [See](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

Answer (score 0):

If no error, it isn't syntax error.

In JSX, [user components should be capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized). `menuBar` results in creating `<menuBar>` DOM element.

`<menuBar/>` JSX is desugared to `React.createElement("menuBar", null)`. While `<MenuBar/>` is desugared to `React.createElement(MenuBar, null)`.

Since the component is default export, it's only import name that needs to be changed:

```
import MenuBar from './menuBar';
```