# Why doesn't this react ternary return work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a slideboard that needs to display a "warning" component (just a "test" div for now) when a prop called "columnsItem" is greater than 50.

It works well but when I try to come back to a slideboard with less columns, I get a white screen. Do you know what I did wrong?
Thanks a lot!

```
class SlideboardWrapper extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    columnsItem: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    angular.bootstrap(this.container, ['slideboardIntegration']);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    angular.element('slideboard-smart').trigger('$destroy');
  }

  render() {
    const { columnsItem } = this.props;

    if (columnsItem < 5 && columnsItem !== 0) return <div> test </div>;

    return (
      <div
        style={{ height: '100%' }}
        ref={(c) => {
          this.container = c;
        }}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
                                  <slideboard-smart></slideboard-smart>
                                  `,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a ternary, what do you mean by this?

Comment: Why angular is being tagged?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar: `angular.element`?

Comment: Oh you're right, I tried so much things that I mixed it up in my mind, I tried ternary and if didn't work either, so I've put an if condition instead.
And about the angular tag, the slideboard-smart is an angular module

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram Oh, I din't see that.

Comment: @GuillaumeMarc do you want to show EITHER `test` or `slideboard` component at one time or both if condition is met?

Comment: @GuillaumeMarc angular tag is added by SO itself since you've `angular.bootstrap`, `angular.element` in the code. Though, it's unnecessary to your query, you can remove the tag by pressing `Edit tags` link.

Comment: @FrancisLeigh If condition is met I just want the test to appear, the issues appears when I come back to the slideboard. The <slideboard-smart> is just empty.
I thought it might be an issue with the ref maybe? I don't know how to work around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found a solution by just exporting the components.
The issue was coming from the $destroy of the angular.bootstrap that didn't work unless the whole class was removed from the dom for some reason.

```
  render() {
    const { columnsItem } = this.props;

    return (
      columnsItem < 5 ? <ColumnHandlerComponent /> : <SlideboardComponent />
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue in your code:

```
<slideboard-smart></slideboard-smart>
```

Notice that component is not capitalized. It should be used like:

```
<SlideboardSmart />
```

Though, this is a duplicate post to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458716/react-cannot-use-import-as-component/52458791#52458791), I have not marked it as duplicate in this scenario, it's a little bit different than that post - dashed style that might be confusing to someone.

In the attached post, someone can use hook like `{slide()}`, but here we cannot use `{slideboard-smart()}` - syntax error.

---

Now, to your query: why it is showing blank?

It's because, when you use lowercase component (defined by user), it will return `null`. It just transformed to like:

```
React.createElement("slideboard-smart", null)
```

ignoring everything that `slideboard-smart` may have.

---

To your solution, you can use like this:

```
if (columnsItem < 5 && columnsItem !== 0) return <div> test </div>;

return (
  <div
    style={{ height: '100%' }}
    ref={(c) => {
      this.container = c;
    }}
  >
    <SlideboardSmart />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I didn't write this component which is an angular.module, that may be why it is written like that?
I'm not an angular expert so I couldn't say, but i don't think that it is the issue here, given that it was working well like that before I tried to implement the "test".

Comment: You can't use that. You must have capitalized component. Just try as my answer suggests to you. You'll be seeing working after then. And other issue, I can't understand what you mean - didn't get your query with condition.

Comment: I don't know I didn't say that, my issue is basically that I need to implement a "test" component that replaces the "slideboard" when the variable columnsItem is smaller than 5.
It works but when I want to go back to the slideboard **from** the "test" component, I get an empty <slideboard-smart> component. A white page basically.
It works from the "slideboard" to the "test", but not the other way around.
I don't know if I'm clear?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes I did, it didn't change the issue unfortunatly.

Comment: Clearly, I'm not sure what you want exactly with the condition - it's really confusing to me as like everyone seems.

Comment: Well I'll try to explain, I have a slideboard (slideboard-smart). If it has less than 5 columns, I want to render the <div>test<div> instead of the slideboard
And vice versa.
it works when I have less than five columns.
But when I'm in the "test" div and I add more than 5 columns, the slideboard is empty

Answer (score -1):

```
return columnsItem > 50 ? '<div>test</div>' : '';
```

For JSX

```
return (
 { columnsItem > 50 
    ? '<div>test</div>' 
    : '' 
 }
      <div
        style={{ height: '100%' }}
        ref={(c) => {
          this.container = c;
        }}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
                                  <slideboard-smart></slideboard-smart>
                                  `,
        }}
      />
    );
```

Comment: This would never return the slide-board component.

Comment: No, it wouldn't but the basics of a ternary are correct. With the right knowledge of JSX you can make this work!

Comment: But then the slideboard would always render... i think the OP is to either show "test" OR slideboard

Comment: What I understood is that the slideboard should always render. As stated by OP 'It works well but when I try to come back to a slideboard with less columns, I get a white screen. Do you know what I did wrong? Thanks a lot!'...

Comment: I think that is now the case. XD

Comment: Actually it's not both, when there's more than 50 columns, the slideboard is replaced by that state element and when there's less that 50 you can come back to the slideboard.
I can show the slideboard, then show the test by adding 50 columns, the issue is when I try to come back to the slideboard from the test
It's a bit confusing sorry about that